# Responsive SVG ( Truncation Following Resize )

Tags: svg, reactive, bootstrap-5

I'm currently attempting to implement an API that generates a radial progress using SVG.

Here is an example of what occurs when i resize the parent div to something smaller.

[image]

Can anyone suggest a solution to make the SVG resize in respect to the parent container?

I have tried using the viewbox attribute on the SVG element with undesirable results.

Here is an example of my markup:

```css
  text {
      text-anchor: middle;
      font-weight: bolder;
      font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  }
  .shadow {
      -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(6px 6px 10px #000000cc);
      filter: drop-shadow(6px 6px 10px #000000cc);
  }
```

```html
<div id="svg-container" class="containter" style="width: 180px;height:280px">
    <svg id="svg" width="100%" height="100%" >
        <defs>
            <filter id="inset-drop-shadow">
                <feFlood flood-color="#000000" />
                <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="out" />
                <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="6" result="blur" />
                <feComposite operator="atop" in2="SourceGraphic" />
            </filter>
        </defs>
        <circle cx="50%" cy="50%"  r="138" stroke="#ccc" stroke-width="1" fill="#999" />
        <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="135" stroke="#ccc" stroke-width="1" fill="#efefef" filter="url(#inset-drop-shadow)" />
        <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="105" stroke="#ccc" stroke-width="1" fill="#fff" class="shadow" />
    
        <text x="50%" y="40%" font-size="35" fill="#555">Value</text>
        <text x="50%" y="60%" font-size="45" fill="#555">100.0<tspan>%</tspan></text>
    
        <path x="50%" y="50%" id="arc1" fill="none" stroke="#0f0" stroke-width="27" filter="url(#inset-drop-shadow)" />
        <path x="50%" y="50%" id="arc2" fill="none" stroke="#999" stroke-width="10">
            <title>Target 80%</title>
        </path> 
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: What's undesirable about a viewBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View box is the simplest solution for this case. Otherwise, you'll have to pass width and height explicitly to svg and calculate all coordinates and sizes acordingly

```html
<div id="svg-container" class="containter" style="width: 180px;height:280px">
    <svg id="svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 280 280">
        <defs>
            <filter id="inset-drop-shadow">
                <feFlood flood-color="#000000" />
                <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="out" />
                <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="6" result="blur" />
                <feComposite operator="atop" in2="SourceGraphic" />
            </filter>
        </defs>
        <circle cx="50%" cy="50%"  r="138" stroke="#ccc" stroke-width="1" fill="#999" />
        <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="135" stroke="#ccc" stroke-width="1" fill="#efefef" filter="url(#inset-drop-shadow)" />
        <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="105" stroke="#ccc" stroke-width="1" fill="#fff" class="shadow" />
    
        <text x="50%" y="40%" font-size="35" fill="#555" text-anchor="middle">Value</text>
        <text x="50%" y="60%" font-size="45" fill="#555" text-anchor="middle">100.0<tspan>%</tspan></text>
    
        <path x="50%" y="50%" id="arc1" fill="none" stroke="#0f0" stroke-width="27" filter="url(#inset-drop-shadow)" />
        <path x="50%" y="50%" id="arc2" fill="none" stroke="#999" stroke-width="10">
            <title>Target 80%</title>
        </path> 
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice mate, i'll revisit viewbox and see what it takes to make it work for me